# I have a problems with xpath, i need href link and other <a> attributes

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I need get some part of a tag. My XML is like that

```
    <div class="item">
<h2><a href="url.html" title="siomethink">Vyzivovy poradca</a></h2>
...
...
<div class="watch"><a href="sth" data-id="292931" data-active="somethink" data-inactive="blablalba" data-class="monitored" class="watchItem" title="watching"><span>sometihink</span></a></div>
</div>
```

And I need href attribute and "data-id" attribute. My template look like

```
<xsl:variable name="url" select="xhtml:h2/xhtml:a/href"/>
<xsl:variable name="job_id" select="xhtml:div[@class = 'watch']/xhtml:a/data-id"/>

<job>
<xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$job_id"/></xsl:attribute>
<url name="url"><xsl:value-of select="$url"/></url>

</job>
```

and template for tag a is:

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:a">
<xsl:copy>
    <!-- can not copy href, cause it is not absolute url ! -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="@align|@title|@rel|@itemprop|@itemtype|@itemscope"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::xhtml:pre]"><xsl:value-of select="etl:regex-replace(., '(\s|\n)+', '$1', 'g')"/></xsl:template>
```

but it doesn't work, some ideas?

Comment: I tried this...

<xsl:variable name="url" select="xhtml:h2/xhtml:a/href"/>
<xsl:variable name="job_id" select="xhtml:div[@class = 'watch']/xhtml:a/data-id"/>

<job>
<xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$job_id"/></xsl:attribute>
<url name="url"><xsl:value-of select="$url"/></url>

</job>

you cen see it in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This input XML:**

```
<div class="item">
  <h2>
    <a href="url.html" title="siomethink">Vyzivovy poradca</a>
  </h2>
  ...
  ...
  <div class="watch">
    <a href="sth"
       data-id="292931"
       data-active="somethink"
       data-inactive="blablalba"
       data-class="monitored"
       class="watchItem"
       title="watching"><span>sometihink</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Given to this XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="//a[descendant::text() = 'sometihink']">
    <root>
      <href>
        <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
      </href>
      <data-id>
        <xsl:value-of select="@data-id"/>
      </data-id>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Produces this output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <href>sth</href>
   <data-id>292931</data-id>
</root>
```

**Notes:**

- I'm assuming that the "`sometihink`" content is the most unique
  characteristic of the `a` you seek.  If it's something else (such as the parent `div[@class="watch"]`), let me know and we can adjust.

---

### Update per OP's comment below:

**This *updated* XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <item-href>
        <xsl:value-of select="//div[@class='item']/h2/a/@href"/>
      </item-href>
      <watch-data-id>
        <xsl:value-of select="//div[@class='watch']/a/@data-id"/>
      </watch-data-id>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Given the above input XML will yield this output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <item-href>url.html</item-href>
   <watch-data-id>292931</watch-data-id>
</root>
```

containing the requested attribute values.

Comment: no sometihink is not unique, like div class, sometihink is different in every div class="item"... unique parts is div[@class="watch"] and <div class="item"> and other tags. And I dont need  <href>sth</href>, but I need  <href>url.html</href>

Comment: Ah, ok, will update answer... ...done.  Let me know if that's it.